# SPWeb.ProcessBatchData and checked out file

Tags: development

I'm using `SPWeb.ProcessBatchData` to update a bunch of items in an efficient way.

However, when I try to update files that are in a folder that requires check out to edit, I get errors telling me the file is not check out.

I only want to change one field of the metadata of the file (an order column).

Is there a way to batch update checked in files?

Something similar to the `SPlistItem.SystemUpdate` method?

Answer (score 1):

I think the workaround for this can be to disable list versioning before the `processbatchdata` is run and then enabling it again after it is completed. That way the files will remain checked-in after the process is completed.

Answer (score 0):

you could do a check on each file if its checked out?

```
foreach(SPlistItem item in list.items)
{
    SPFile file = item.File;

    //checks to see if its checked in and NOT checked out!
    if (file.CheckOutStatus == SPFile.SPCheckOutStatus.None)
    {
        //do your stuff
    }
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.spcheckouttype.aspx

Comment: Checking the file is checked out is simple, but this won't help me to batch update my items. If I have to checkout the file before updating it, I loose the benefits of the batch update